# webview app: choosing a file doesn't work

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm setting up my webview app and I would like "choose file" button to be able to upload pictures from my phone, but now that button does not have any function or does not work. Please if anyone can help me, thank you in advance!

This is from MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://example.com");
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

And this is from AndroidManifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: please provide more information, please share the log cat and console messages

Comment: you have to implement it manually, WebVIew does not have it by default. To find how - use search, it's easy to find

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to find it? I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

*Follow the stated code below* :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
private String urlStart = "http://www.example.com/mobile/";

private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE   = 2888;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;

//Camera parameters
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

webView.loadUrl(urlStart);

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) { 

        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

        try{
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File externalDataDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                      Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
            File cameraDataDir = new File(externalDataDir.getAbsolutePath() +
                      File.separator + "browser-photos");
            cameraDataDir.mkdirs();
            String mCameraFilePath = cameraDataDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                      System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFilePath));

            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");

            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[] { cameraIntent });

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
          }
         catch(Exception e){
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera Exception:"+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
       }

    // For Android < 3.0
   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg ) {
           openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
       }

// For Android  > 4.1.1
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
           openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
       }

       public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {        
           onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
           return true;
       }
       public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) 
  {
           Log.d("androidruntime", "www.example.com: " + message);
         }
});
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE){  
        if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
            return;
        }

       Uri result=null;

       try{
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                result = null;

            } else {
                // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData(); 
            } 
        } catch(Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set **WebChromeClient** for Choose File in webview

CODE IS HERE

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;
private String url = "www.example.com";
private ValueCallback<Uri> msgUpload;
private final static int CHOOSER_FILE_RESULT_CODE = 100;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

    initViews();
    setListeners();
}

private void initViews() {
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

}

private void setListeners()
{
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

            webView.loadUrl("about:blank");

            view.clearHistory();
        }


    });

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {


        }

        // For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            msgUpload = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                    CHOOSER_FILE_RESULT_CODE);
        }

        //For Android 4.1 and above
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            msgUpload = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), CHOOSER_FILE_RESULT_CODE);

        }


    });



        webView.loadUrl(url);


    final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface
            = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (webView.canGoBack() == true) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == CHOOSER_FILE_RESULT_CODE) {
        if (null == msgUpload) return;
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                : intent.getData();
        msgUpload.onReceiveValue(result);
        msgUpload= null;
    }
}

public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void openAndroidDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder myDialog
                = new AlertDialog.Builder(WebViewActivity.this);
        myDialog.setTitle("DANGER!");
        myDialog.setMessage("You can do what you want!");
        myDialog.setPositiveButton("ON", null);
        myDialog.show();
    }

}
```